# Problem with SDV (synthetic data vault): Getting back identical synthetic datasets

Tags: python, data-generation, synthetic, sdv

I'm using the following code from the SDV library to create a synthetic dataset that's the same shape as my original dataset. While each synthetic dataset is different than the original dataset, all synthetic datasets are identical to each other. I would have thought there would be some randomness built into the synthetic data generation process so that each output would be slightly different. This occurs across sessions even when I set a different random seed. How should I interpret what's happening?

````
    metadata.detect_from_dataframe(data=input_data)
    synthesizer = SingleTablePreset(metadata=metadata,name='FAST_ML')
    synthesizer.fit(data=input_data)
    synthetic_data = synthesizer.sample(num_rows=len(input_data))```
````

Answer (score 4):

I believe SDV synthesizers set an internal seed when they run, which explains the determinism you're seeing. This is expected behavior.

If you want different data, you can call the `sample` method multiple times. Every subsequent run should give you different data. In the code below, all 3 samples of synthetic data will be different.

```py
synthetic_data_1 = synthesizer.sample(num_rows=len(input_data))
synthetic_data_2 = synthesizer.sample(num_rows=len(input_data))
synthetic_data_3 = synthesizer.sample(num_rows=len(input_data))
```

For more info, see the [sampling docs](https://docs.sdv.dev/sdv/single-table-data/sampling/sample-realistic-data), particularly the `reset_sampling` method to get back to the initial state.

BTW the team is always looking for feedback. For supporting more randomization options, you can [file a feature request](https://github.com/sdv-dev/SDV/issues/new/choose) directly on the GitHub.